# Boolean Field in mysql db

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, boolean

I want to save my value as a boolean in my mysql database. But somehow Iam not able to save it , mysql automatically saves it of the type tinyInt.Also tell me the default values for boolean. how we pass the values?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In MySQL `BOOLEAN` type is a synonym for `TINYINT`. There is no dedicated `BOOLEAN` type. 
The vaules accepeted, are those for `TINYINT` i.e. 0 for false, 1-255 (preferably 1) for true.

Comment: But why bool and tinyint are different. If they are same there should be one

Comment: There is no 'BOOL'. There's only 'TINYINT' which can be written as 'BOOL'.

Comment: I got it now but I was just confused why they have retained bool in mysql if we can use tinyInt.Bool should be removed from the list.

Comment: It's there for compatibility with other SQL variants. There are other datatypes like that, for example `DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC`.

Answer (score 8):

MySQL doesn't really have a BOOLEAN type, if you create a BOOLEAN column it will actually be a TINYINT.

Treating TINYINT as a boolean isn't too problematic though, if you treat 0 as false and non-0 as true then it's fine.  In PHP a statement like `if ($column)` will return true if $column is any value except 0 or something that evaluates to 0.  If you need it to explicitly be a bool you can convert it easily enough by doing `$column = ($column != 0);`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to hear this. I was wondering how I could set a boolean field in MYSQL.

But seeing that only tinyint is supported, I converted the Boolean values to integers in python, before inserting them into the database.

```
is_holiday = 0
if row[4] != 'FALSE':
    is_holiday = 1
                    
#   insert a record into DB
cursor.execute("INSERT into sales(store, department, date, weekly_sales, is_holiday) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (row[0], int(row[1]), sales_date, float(row[3]), is_holiday))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33548833)

Comment: Treating False values as 0 and True as 1 doesn't prove a qualified answer? @Andy Gee

Comment: Indeed, the question already states "But somehow Iam not able to save it , mysql automatically saves it of the type tinyInt". So the user knows this already and the question is about not using tiny int. The accepted answer explains: "BOOLEAN type is a synonym for TINYINT" and explains how the default values might be applied in the interface phpmyadmin (not as pseudo-code which doesn't apply to phpmyadmin)